# Como normalizar este banco de dados?

Tags: mysql

Estou com um problema ao criar uma Base de dados onde uma empresa pode ter ate 16 trabalhadores. Onde cada trabalhador pode ter estes dados:

```
$sqlupdate3 = "Update tb_detalhe_trabalhador SET
Nome3='$Nome3',Funcao3='$Funcao3',
MedicaValidade3='$MedicaValidade3',
MedicaAnexo3='$MedicaAnexo3',
EPISValidade3='$EPISValidade3',
ProjectistaNumero3='$ProjectistaNumero3',
ProjectistaValidade3='$ProjectistaValidade3',
GasNumero3='$GasNumero3',
GasValidade3='$GasValidade3',
RedesNumero3='$RedesNumero3',
RedesValidade3='$RedesValidade3',
SoldadorNumero3='$SoldadorNumero3',
SoldadorValidade3='$SoldadorValidade3',
MecanicoNumero3='$MecanicoNumero3',
MecanicoValidade3='$MecanicoValidade3',
ClasSoldadorNumero3='$ClasSoldadorNumero3', 
ClasSoldadorValidade3='$ClasSoldadorValidade3'
  where id=$id ";

 mysql_query($sqlupdate3) or die(mysql_error());
```

Será melhor criar uma tabela **empresa** e 16 **trabalhador** ou apenas uma **trabalhador**?

Comment: @Bacco Eu não marcaria como duplicata porque este caso é específico, enquanto a outra pergunta é generalista.

Comment: @Andrey lembre-se que você pode votar para reabrir, se quiser.

Comment: Chris, pesquise sobre normalização: http://www.luis.blog.br/normalizacao-de-dados-e-as-formas-normais.aspx e http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados

Comment: Chris, vou te dar uma dica: O título da sua pergunta não está apropriado. Mude para algo como *"Como normalizar este banco de dados?"* Eu também colocaria o `CREATE TABLE` em SQL ao invés do `UPDATE` em PHP na pergunta.

Comment: Dê uma espiada nisso depois, tem um exemplo de uso aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98bf7/2 . - 
No exemplo tem mais de uma empresa, e um select que mostra como pegar de uma só, e tem um JOIN para mesclar os dados da empresa e do trabalhador num select só depois.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode normalizar seguindo o padrão das 5 Formas Normais(FNs) dado esse exemplo abaixo de uma locadora por ser mais simples e apresentar menos tabelas após ser normatizada:
[image: 1FN]

[image: 2FN]

[image: 3FN]

[image: 4FN]

Penso que a proposta desse site seja esclarecer ou ajudar na solução do problema e não fazer por completo um dado problema apresentando toda sua solução. O desenvolvimento do problema parte da sua pessoa a partir do entendimento do problema.

Comment: Ainda poderias acrescentar uma tabela de Categorias de Filmes, essa Base de Dados não está normalizada.

Comment: Esta sim normalizada.. o que pode você pode fazer é apenas uma melhoria para diminuir a redundância de dados/valores repetindo as regras 4F e 5F. Pois as regras 1F,2F 3F são as que determinam realmente a normalização do banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

O ideal seria separar tudo o que fosse possível, por exemplo até as funções dos funcionários, deveria haver uma tabela chamada funções e ali serem cadastradas e depois vinculadas por ID aos funcionários. A questão é que são poucos, funcionários o que resultaria em fazer apenas uma tabela para generalizar, mas é como eu penso: Hoje existem 16 amanhã pode ter 20, 30, 100...

Comment: ok, mas sendo apenas necessario 16 tabelas como consigo relacionar as 16 tabelas as empresas? E como consigo por exemplo em algum caso que a empresa tenha 4 trabalhadores como consigo dizer a bd que as tabelas 5,6,7,8,9 e por ai fora que está vazia?

Comment: @ChrisAdler eu reli quase todas as suas perguntas e as respostas, e ainda nao entendi uma coisa. Qual o problema de ter UMA tabela "trabalhadores", e colocar os registros nesta tabela? Mas nao na mesma linha, como você faz, e sim em linhas separadas.

Comment: Porque ter uma tabela muito extensa e estar a dar erro pelo tamanho dos campos. Queria uma solução para resolver este meu problema

Comment: @ChrisAdler uma tabela com 16 linhas nao seria extensa. Está ficando extensa por que você está pondo mais de um trabalhador na mesma linha, simplesmente isso. Você precisaria de uma tabela com UM nome, UMA função só, etc, e nesta tabela faria varios INSERTS, um para cada trabalhador.

Comment: @ChrisAdler Na linha 1 você teria o nome do primeiro trabalhador, na linha 2 o nome do segundo trabalhador, etc. Do jeito que está fazendo, você pos o nome1 e o nome2 na mesma linha. Aí não há tabela que caiba. Tabelas normalmente tem colunas e linhas (sinonimo de campos e registros). Você está criando campos onde deveria criar registros.

Comment: E depois como consigo relacionar a tabela 1 tabela 2 e tabela 3 com a tb_empresa?

Comment: @ChrisAdler inserindo o ID da empresa em cada uma das linhas de trabalhadores. Do seu jeito você está perdendo um tempo imenso pra resolver uma coisa simples, por insistência. De qq forma, desejo boa sorte. Mas vá tentando, quem sabe alguém responde da forma que você quer, tem um pessoal bem bacana no site. O que eu digo é, com 16 tabelas, voce se complica, e com tudo numa linha só, tambem se complica. Se tiver uma tabela só pra empresa, e uma só pra trabalhadores, com varias linhas, o ID resolve.

Comment: Era aqui que queria chegar.. Agora imagine que apenas tem 2 trabalhadores. as outras tabelas ficam com id vazio correcto? quando for preencher a empresa seguinte fica com o id da empresa anterior

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15363/discussion-between-bacco-and-chrisadler).