# Unir resultados e cruzar com outra tabela

Tags: mysql

Tenho duas tabelas no MySQL:

table_agendamentos:

```
id - tratamentos
1  - 1
2  - 1,2,3
3  - 2,3
```

table_tratamentos:

```
id - nome
1  - Facial
2  - Corporal
3  - Outros
```

Eu quero fazer uma consulta onde consiga retornar o seguinte resultado:

```
id - tratamentos_id - tratamentos_nomes
1  - 1              - Facial
2  - 1,2,3          - Facial, Corporal, Outros
3  - 2,3            - Corporal, Outros
```

Comment: Só de olho recomendo normalizar adequadamente a `table_agendamentos`. Não tem problema repetir a id caso os campos sejam chaves compostas.

Comment: Se você não souber do que o @gmsantos está falando, veja um exemplo em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33794/74

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que você possa normalizar a `table_agendamentos` conforme os comentários, é possível chegar ao resultado que você deseja com um [`group_concat`](http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysqls-group_concat/).

Tabela agendamentos normalizada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
SELECT a.id_agendamento, GROUP_CONCAT(t.id), GROUP_CONCAT(t.nome) 
FROM table_agendamentos a
INNER JOIN table_tratamentos t ON t.id = a.id_tratamentos
GROUP BY a.id_agendamento;
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo no [**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d52f/1)

Answer (score -1):

Segue uma possibilidade:

Crie uma tabela e indique separado por registros o id e os tratamentos possíveis.

```
CREATE TABLE `table_agendamentos` (
   `id_table_agendamentos` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `id_agendamento` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `id_tratamentos` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id_table_agendamentos`)
);

INSERT INTO `table_agendamentos` VALUES
(1,1,1),(2,2,1),(3,2,2),(4,2,3),(5,3,2),(6,3,3);
```

Mantenha a tabela abaixo:

```
CREATE TABLE `tabe_tratamentos` (
  `id_tabe_tratamentos` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_tabe_tratamentos`)
);

INSERT INTO `tabe_tratamentos` VALUES (1,'Facial'),(2,'Corporal'),(3,'Outros');
```

Agora para retornar o que você deseja faca a seguinte SQL:

```
select * from tabe_tratamentos where id_tabe_tratamentos IN (

SELECT id_tratamentos FROM table_agendamentos where id_agendamento = 2)
```

ou

```
Select TT.nome from tabe_tratamentos as TT 
Inner join table_agendamentos as TA ON TA.id_tratamentos = TT.id_tabe_tratamentos 
where TA.id_agendamento = 2;
```

Todos os resultados:

```
Select TA.id_agendamento,  GROUP_CONCAT(TT.nome) from tabe_tratamentos as TT 
Inner join table_agendamentos as TA
ON TA.id_tratamentos = TT.id_tabe_tratamentos
GROUP BY TA.id_agendamento;
```

Comment: Mas essa query final não chega ao resultado esperado na questão

Comment: Alterei o post:testa assim:select * from tabe_tratamentos where id_tabe_tratamentos IN (

SELECT id_tratamentos FROM table_agendamentos where id_agendamento = 2)

Comment: O select continua errado

Comment: Ai o que vocë pode fazer é especificar para qual tipo de agendamento vocë quer  na linha where TA.id_agendamento = 2; e ir refinando a sql.

Comment: Mas na pergunta o Felipe quer todos os nomes de tratamentos em uma única linha para todos os agendamentos.

Comment: Select TA.id_agendamento, GROUP_CONCAT(TT.id_tabe_tratamentos), GROUP_CONCAT(TT.nome)  from tabe_tratamentos as TT 
Inner join table_agendamentos as TA
ON TA.id_tratamentos = TT.id_tabe_tratamentos
GROUP BY TA.id_agendamento;

;

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17848/discussion-between-gmsantos-and-israel-zebulon).