# Por que o group_concat de chaves primárias (números inteiros) gera como resultado um BLOB?

Tags: mysql

Tentando responder [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/36751/unir-resultados-e-cruzar-com-outra-tabela) questão (tal como o AP apresentou mesmo, sem recorrer a normalização) eu tentei usar o  `group_concat` ele me retorna o objecto do tipo `BLOB`.

Tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE `teste` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Dados na Tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consulta:

```
SELECT group_concat(t.id) FROM teste t;
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Há algum problema no MySQL Query Browser? Na consulta?

**Nota:**

Na questão em causa, eu vi exemplos que funcionou certinho mais aqui nada.
No `Workbench` funcionou direitinho, a mesma consulta.

Comment: Muito estranho... Poderia [edit] sua pergunta incluindo suas tabelas, dados e consultas?

Comment: Perdoe ai @gmsantos, faltou a consulta, os dados já estão ai certo?

Comment: Um `create table` seria mais útil que a imagem, se não se importar em editar.

Comment: Na boa @gmsantos...

Comment: Está ai @gmsantos, coloquei o script para criação da tabela.

Comment: Parece ser um bug numa versão antiga do workbench isso, poderia postar o que retorna a query : `show variables like "%concat%";` ?

Comment: Humm... o resultado é de 1024.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17861/discussion-between-gmsantos-and-cold).

Comment: Acho logico. Acho que vc faz uma confuzão entre o tipo dentro da BDD e o tipo dos resultados. Por exemplo, se vc tem um tabela com varchar(150) de um lado e varchar(300) de outro lado, vc não vai poder ter um resultado que vai concordar com os 2 tipos porque vc pode ter um resultado de 450 car. Se agora vc tem um varchar(300) e que vc quere fazer um group_concat com 1000 valors, vc vai ter no final 300.000 car. O que não pode ser colocado num varchar.
Neste caso, o resultado não tem realmente um "tipo". Ele e somente acumulação de valor.

Comment: Parece que é um Bug @Peter. Quanto a explicação da lógica nisso ainda nao percebi muito bem. Vou reler seu comentário.

Comment: O que quero dizer e que o resultado não tem "tipo". O que tem "tipo" são somente os dados dentro da BDD.

Comment: Então não é um bug, esta correto é isso @Peter?

Comment: Correto. Conforme na resposta de Antony, o resultado não pode ser do mesmo tipo que os dados porque em muitos casos, o tamaho do resultado ultrapasa o tamaho do tipo dos dados.

Answer (score 7):

Conforme o [manual do SQL: `group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

> The return value is a nonbinary or binary string, depending on whether the arguments are nonbinary or binary strings. The result type is `TEXT` or `BLOB` unless `group_concat_max_len` is less than or equal to 512, in which case the result type is `VARCHAR` or `VARBINARY`.

Em resumo exitem dois fatores que determinam o tipo de retorno da função agregada `group_concat`:

1. Se a variável `group_concat_max_len` é menor ou igual a 512 serão usados tipos de tamanho variável (`VARCHAR` ou`VARBINARY`). Se for maior do que 512 serão usados lobs (`TEXT` ou `BLOB`).
2. O formato do tipo de origem: Se for uma string binária será gerada uma string binária (`VARBINARY`,ou `BLOB`), se for textual serão usados tipos não binários (`VARCHAR` ou `TEXT`).

No seu caso em específico sua variável `group_concat_max_len` está setada para um valor maior do que 512 e o `id` é do tipo `int`. Na verão 5.1 esse número é interpretado (convertido implicitamente) como uma string binária, já em versões recentes ele é interpretado como uma string não binária.

Logo, a função retorna:

- um tipo `BLOB` para a versão 5.1, ou
- um tipo `TEXT` para versões modernas (a não ser que você converta o tipo para uma string binária `SELECT group_concat(BINARY t.id) AS coluna FROM teste t;`)

---

#### Exemplos:

- [MySQL 5.1.61](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/1009e/1) (`LONGBLOB`)
- [MySQL 5.5.32](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1009e7/1) (`TEXT`)
- [MySQL 5.6.6 m9 - Binary](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc28c/1) (`BLOB`)

Comment: Mas por que isso só ocorre no mysql 5.1 e no query browser ?

Comment: Houve uma mudança de comportamento na hora de interpretar o int entre a versão 5.1 e 5.5 (veja update). O query browser não tem nada a ver com a história.

Comment: Boa @Anthony. Sua resposta faz mais sentido que a minha.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly então porquê usando o WorkBench 5.2.31 CE ele funciona direito, não percebi bem esta parte.

Comment: @Cold talvez o workbench esteja apontando para outra instância, o que retorna se rodar `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%"` no Workbench?

Comment: @gmsantos não me parece: 5.1.53

Comment: Cara, o [Query Browser](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/query/) foi descontinuado (O [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), entre outras coisas, assumiu as função de UI para consulta). Dito isso, conforme minha resposta, se você está usando o MySQL 5.1 ele vai interpretar o valor como uma string binária e gerar um BLOB (como no exemplo, que não usa o Query Browser nem o Workbench). Pode ser que o Workbench esteja interpretando os resultados da string binária ou algo assim, mas se você usar a tabela do meu exemplo verificará que o tipo é um `LONGBLOB` na versão 5.1.