# Selecionar apenas colunas com valores

Tags: sql

Possuo uma tabela com uma sequencia de campos com quase o mesmo nome, alterando apenas o caractere final, e preciso fazer uma consulta que retorne apenas as colunas com algum valor, atualmente faço o seguinte:

```
select pag, descricao,cod_vcto1,cod_vcto2,cod_vcto3,cod_vcto4,cod_vcto5 from tabela_exemplo where pag =2;

pag descricao   cod_vcto1   cod_vcto2   cod_vcto3   cod_vcto4   cod_vcto5
2   28 DIAS         28          31      null       null        null
```

Gostaria de retornar, apenas 28 DIAS 28/31. Porem eu possuo 15 colunas que começam com cod_vcto, as quais variam de cod_vcto1 até cod_vcto15, existe alguma maneira de selecionar apenas as colunas que não são nulas?

Comment: Thiago, na sua query você não consegue "adivinhar" qual coluna estará vazia e remove-la do seu select. Além disse, se possível, revise a estrutura da sua tabela. Em vez de 15 cod_vcto, basta uma única coluna repetindo o id e descrição. Isso que sugeri se chama normalização e mais detalhes você pode encontrar nessa [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33794/74)

Comment: @Thiago, Parece realmente que seu schema foi mal normalizado e falta uma tabela de relacionamento entre vencimentos e a tabela_exemplo. Não obstante você pode fazer uso de COALESCE para retornar algo no lugar do null. Quanto a retornar dinamicamente diferentes colunas, dá p/ fazer gambiarras horríveis com queries dinâmicas mas aconselho fortemente a não fazer isso

Answer (score 1):

Como sugeriu o gmsantos a solução limpa é normalizar , mas uma solução suja (e muito) é simplesmente concatenar (convertendo a string) as colunas o resultado será somente as colunas com valor, não haveria cabeçalho para indicar "qual".

Mas recomendo uma normalização ao menos que haja um bom motivo para o modelo atual.

Answer (score 0):

Desconheço qualquer forma de fazer um select que retorne somente as colunas que não estão nulas, porem se está utilizando alguma linguagem de programação para estar fazendo a aplicação, você pode criar uma classe-objeto e fazer uma lista com os objetos, e assim pegando somente as colunas desejadas!

espero ter ajudado!

Comment: entendo, acredito que com o select apenas vai ser dificil, obrigado pela resposta.